# Suppress user agents max-age=0 header

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, http-headers

The `Cache-Control: max-age=0` header coming from the browser is causing the static assets with md5 cache buster in my rails 3.1 app to not get cached permanently because the browser is asking for a complete revalidation of the caches and getting a 304 not modified. I want that the browser use its own cache and never revalidate. My server is sending the following header `max-age=31536000, public`.

Comment: I don't understand. `Cache-Control` is usually sent with the response, not the request. Can you clarify this?

Comment: @awendt The `Cache-Control` header has meaning both ways, and `max-age` is also meaningful both ways in HTTP 1.1.

Answer (score 0):

`Cache-Control: max-age=0` from the user agent is the user agent's way of requesting that any content in the cache be revalidated. You can't send anything to the client to stop it sending this header value. See http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.3. The only thing you can do is configure the caches in front of your application to ignore it and send what would be considered stale (according to the user agent) content back to the user agent, which should be possible.